MongoDB read operation is unsuccessful
My code is returning no data from mongodb when I am using res.json(), but when I am using console.log() it is showing the data.
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const app = express();
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://dontlook:nottheactualpass@cluster0.ccflqch.mongodb.net/dashboard");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        end_year : String,
        intensity : String
})
const model = mongoose.model("dataset", schema);

app.get("/getData", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await model.find({});
        res.json(data);
        console.log(model.find({}))
    } catch (err) {
        
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
});



app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log(`App is running at http://localhost:3000/getData`)
})

I was expecting api output at localhost:3000


How does the data look like when it is being printed to the console (any hints that res.json might not know how to serialize it) and what does "returning no data" mean exactly?

return res.json()

the printed output is too long,
returning no data as in, at localhost:3000/getData there is only an empty array showing ([]) when it should show
[{end_year: 2000,
intensity: 6}]

My collection is filled with json data, but the code is not returning the data from the collection dataset of database dashboard.

@underscore I doubt return makes any difference here

What happens when you do console.log(data)?

Empty array [ ] means your code connected to the database but zero documents were found. Based on your Model mongoose is looking for a collection named datasets inside the dashboard database. You need to make sure that matches what you expect. You should also get rid of the console.log(model.find({})) as all that does is log a an instance of Query.

@jQueeny yes, I have made sure that the names of collection and database is dataset and dashboard, but my collection is filled with json data there is no possibility of it being empty.

If your collection is named dataset then mongoose won't find documents. Mongoose uses the first parameter of mongoose.model() and lowercase pluralises it for the collection so it will look for datasets not dataset
